# Understanding how backbone collection fetch and model fetch work

Tags: backbone.js

So, when i try to send a collection from server with duplicate entry (same id) backbone doesn't render that element.

But on model.fetch() if i return a model with  an already existing id,  it works.So now we have a collection with same ids.

Why is this different behaviour, i was thinking backbone will verify(check if that id alread exist) the incoming model before updating it  and not render it.

**EDIT**

on collection.fetch i get this

var  coll = [{name: 'foo', id: 1 }, {'name': 'bar', id: 2 }] // just representation;

now i do model.fetch() for second model,  and the server responds this

{'name': 'new bar', 'id': 1} //  no-error the view gets updated

Comment: Some code to illustrate your question would help tremendously.

Comment: http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html

Comment: @Michael.Lumley thnx for the link, but that does'nt answer the question.. please reply if you understood the question.

Comment: model.fetch() fetches an individual model back from the server.How do you say you have a collection of models with simillar id's ? Can you post the code ?